# Template 10 HamburgerButtonInfo Got_Focus not implemented

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I would like to use the Got_Focus within the template 10 HamburgerButtonInfo .

```
    <Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaNav" AutoPlay="True" />

    <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu" >

        <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
            <!--  mainpage button  -->
            <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ClearHistory="True" PageType="views:MainPage"  AutomationProperties.Name="Jerry" >                                       
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Home" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Home"  />
                    <!--<Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="120"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" Height="48"  />-->
                </StackPanel>
            </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>
    </Grid>
```

If I understand correctly, the Got_Focus really should be at the HamburgerButtonInfo level, however it is not available.
Could anyone let me know how this could be implemented?

Thanks in advance.